# Using JavaScript/jQuery to insert an image into last last column when using CSS3 webkit-columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have content flowing in 3 columns using -webkit-columns: 3 and want to insert an image in the top of the last column (far right column). CSS3 Regions is possible future solution but not ready for primetime. This solution is my only work around. A possible solution is to use "webkitColumnCount" with JavaScript and insert the image to the top of the 3rd column. Is this the right approach? I'm looking for creative solutions or suggestions. This only needs to work for Webkit as this is an iPad only implementation.

Comment: But wouldn't inserting the image change the cumulative height of the content, causing the column allocation to be recalculated, which *could* result in the image being displayed at the bottom of the second column?

Comment: I suggest you create a jsfiddle to show what you mean and what you have done so far

Comment: I have added an example of what I'm trying to achieve. http://jsbin.com/abuneb/3 I want to use JavaScript or jQuery to insert the image into the top of the last column.